# How to add some jQuery plugin done callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, methods, callback

my question is how to add to some jQuery pugin like this example...

```
$('#Div').myPluginLoad();
```

add done callback like this...

```
$('#Div').myPluginLoad().done(function(){
    alert('task finished..!!');
});
```

to execute another function....

in my plugin :

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.extend({    
        myPluginLoad: function (options) {    

            //  defaults
            var defaults = {
                padding: 20,
                mouseOverColor: '#000000',
                mouseOutColor: '#ffffff'
            }    
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);    
            return this.each(function () {    
                /**
                 *    SOME ASYNC TASK
                 **/    
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Plz, help!!

Comment: You would stop doing return this.each, and instead generate a defferrd object and return it's promise object, then resolve it when you want the done callback to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.extend({    
        myPluginLoad: function (options) {    
            var def = $.Deferred();

            //  defaults
            var defaults = {
                padding: 20,
                mouseOverColor: '#000000',
                mouseOutColor: '#ffffff'
            }    
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var deferredList = [];

            this.each(function () { 
                var innerDef = $.Deferred();
                deferredList.push(innerDef.promise());

                $.ajax({...}) //just for example
                .done(function() {
                    innerDef.resolve();                    
                });
            });

            $.when.apply($, deferredList).done(function() {
               def.resolve(); 
            });

            return def.promise();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You would need to create a deferred object to return that represents when all the items have finished loading. You would then need to create another deferred for each iteration of `this.each()`. When all of those deferreds have been resolved, resolve the one that you returned.

Comment: THIS WORKED PERFECTLY FOR MY ... THIS IS WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR, AND EVERY INSTANCE, KEEP YOUR OWN VALUES. THANKS A LOT...!!

Comment: sorry for not voting your answer but I have not enough points to allow me to vote ....

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. You _should_ be able to accept the answer even if you can't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Deferred objects.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.extend({    
        myPluginLoad: function (options) {    

            //  defaults
            var defaults = {
                padding: 20,
                mouseOverColor: '#000000',
                mouseOutColor: '#ffffff'
            }
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return $.Deferred(function(def){
                // the async task
                setTimeout(function(){
                    def.resolve();
                },5000);
            }).promise();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean callbacks??

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.extend({    
        myPluginLoad: function (options,callback) {    

            //  defaults
            var defaults = {
                padding: 20,
                mouseOverColor: '#000000',
                mouseOutColor: '#ffffff'
            }    
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);    
            return this.each(function () {    
                /**
                 *    SOME TASK
                 **/    
            });
            if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
               callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then use it like this

```
$('#Div').myPluginLoad({
    callback:function(){
       //do your thing here
    }
});
```

Comment: yes... i said callbacks, but what I was looking for was that when finalizing a task in the plugin, execute another external function, but only when finished. But this answer helps me to another problem I had in mind, thanks anyway.

Comment: Good to know that in helped you in some way.. :)